# Different behaviour debug vs release mode android —some features not working

Tags: android, release

I have a screen that has the Drawer on it. The arrow icon on the top action bar and the click to pull the drawer both get disabled on my release version, while they work perfectly fine on my debug version of the app.
Totally clueless why this is happening as there are no feature flags of any kind in the app to turn on or turn off any such features with the build variants. Any help is appreciated since we're close to the release.

Comment: Are you debugging it on emulator only?

Comment: Are you running ProGuard on your release builds? You could turn that off and see if the problem is still reproducible, to help narrow down the issue.

Comment: @Mike I'm running it on a device and testing it

Comment: @kcoppock NO, I'm not running ProGuard. I just install the two variants debug and release available on android studio and this issue happens. The issue happens on the first screen of the app in case of Release. The debug version has one more activity before that first screen. Not sure if Android does something with the first screen specifically. Also this is an issue on Android 4.1. Unfortunately it's a company app and we are releasing on this version so need to figure out the solution in this version only.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the user application has any control over the action of the drawer sliding out when the arrow on the action bar is clicked. I think the action of sliding out the drawer lies with the support library. But still doesn't answer how and why my code could affect the action of a library component.